# Django channel not getting message

Tags: django, django-channels

I am using django channel in my current project. From one of my django app, I am sending notification to the channel layer, so that websocket can broadcast the message. But problem is 
consumer is not getting my message.

Utils in django app for sending notification to channel:

```
from asgiref.sync import AsyncToSync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
import json


def async_send(group_name, text):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    AsyncToSync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'notify',
            'text': json.dumps(text)
        }
    )
```

My consumer file is:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class InformationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def notify(self, event):
        await self.send(
            {
                "message": event['text'],
            },
        )
        print(event['text'])
```

I am supposed to get the output of event['text'], but getting nothing :(

Comment: what is the group name?

Comment: How will you call the utils

Comment: I am calling the group name by the username. like async_send(str(request.user.username), 'Hello ')

Comment: alter this 1 to 2 and 2 nd to 1 self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

Comment: @giveJob Its not working :(

Comment: any error......?

Comment: NO error !  ......

Comment: i think self.send_json is not available in AsyncWebsocketConsumer try to change to self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": event['text']}))

Comment: Yes I know. But it does not work with only send tooo.

Comment: and before adding group called self.scope['user'] and accepting connection check self.scope['user']  is _anonymous or not

Comment: I am printing here. It is similar . no problem here too.

Comment: change  self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)
 toooo await  self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213303/discussion-between-givejob-and-mahbubcseju).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change from

`self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)`

to

`await self.channel_layer.group_add(str(self.scope['user']), self.channel_name)`